# Hibernate 'tableless' enum mapping?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, inheritance, enums

I am dealing with the following scenario:

We use [table-per-subclass inheritance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass), meaning the concrete tables' primary keys are foreign key references on the *abstract* table. Superclass is **Product**, subclasses are **Book**, **DVD**, **AudioCD**, ...

Now in the Java superclass, say `Product.java`, we have an `enum` of the types of products: book, dvd, music, etc.

We have no discriminator column in the abstract table and no extra table for the types.

Is it possible to map the **type** `enum` in `Product.java` to the correct values, depending on the concrete object? Or is a discriminator or an extra table necessary?

... ....

Table per subclass inheritance mapping excerpt:

```
 <class name="Product" table="PRODUCT">
    <id name="id" column="IDPRODUCT" type="int">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    ...

    <joined-subclass name="Book" table="BOOK">
        <key column="IDPRODUCT" />

        <property ...

    </joined-subclass>
 ...
```

... ...

`Product.java`

```
public class Product {

    public enum Type { book, dvd, music }

    ...

    private Type type;

    ...
```

Sounds odd? Maybe. Two separate parties designed the OO part and the DB part ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be missing something, but why would you even have `Type` as a field? Make `getType()` abstract in `Product` and implement it in subclasses to return appropriate value.